# Compilation error due to boost::filesystem

Tags: boost, compiler-errors

I'm compiling a software in Osx and it returned this error:

```
/Users/luca/Software/ros-stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/utilmm/src/configsearch/configuration_finder.cc: In static member function ‘static std::string utilmm::ConfigurationFinder::search(const std::string&, const std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&)’:
  /Users/luca/Software/ros-stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/utilmm/src/configsearch/configuration_finder.cc:56: error: ‘exists’ is not a member of ‘boost::filesystem’
  /Users/luca/Software/ros-stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/utilmm/src/configsearch/configuration_finder.cc:58: error: ‘system_complete’ is not a member of ‘boost::filesystem’
  /Users/luca/Software/ros-stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/utilmm/src/configsearch/configuration_finder.cc:69: error: ‘exists’ is not a member of ‘boost::filesystem’
  /Users/luca/Software/ros-stacks/orocos_toolchain_ros/utilmm/src/configsearch/configuration_finder.cc:71: error: ‘system_complete’ is not a member of ‘boost::filesystem’
```

Does anyone know ho to fix it?

I have boost @1.47.0_0+debug+python26

Thanks Luca

Comment: What version of Boost do you have installed?

Comment: Is configuration_finder.cc your code? Does it have the proper `#include`s? Is your build environment set up so that the correct installation of Boost is found?

Comment: @ildjarn I'm sorry but I'm not really expert of boost. Should I put a link to the source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.orocos.org/forum/rtt/rtt-dev/orocostoolchainros-utilmm-240-compile-error-utilmmsrcconfigsearchconfigurationfind) post on the developer's forums, the issue is a bug in the software you're building that will be fixed in a subsequent release.

Comment: Yes I know. But I'm trying to find a solution :)